# Handsontable Customize Existing Context Menu Items

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am trying to customise a pre-existing handsontable context menu item.

Specifically I would like to add a password prompt to to the 'Read only' option in the context menu so only authorized users can modify the data in the table. I have developed the following code for the customizing the context menu as follows:

```
hot.updateSettings({
  contextMenu: {
    items:  {
            "make_read_only": {
              //how to I keep the exisiting functionality but add a 
              //password prompt?
            }
          }
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand that what you're trying to achieve is a very good 'nice to have', but I hope your writting permission security is not only based on this feature. Keep in mind that you should "never trust the client".

Comment: @fap Correct permission security is not only based on this feature. Our client has requested this to ensure anyone who wants to modify the data in the handsontable is 100% sure they want to modify it before read only status is cleared.